# The underlying cause of Flat Earth beliefs

Tags: abnormal-psychology

I've a physics and computer science background but I've always wondered is there an underlying psychological condition(s) associated with groups like flat-earther.

They seem to be prepared to ignore overwhelming evidence in favor of a variety of near-magical concepts to cling to their flat-earth beliefs.  Physics is so well established and so fundamental to our civilization that I wonder if there's a common issue or set of issues that lead people to deny well established science.

I regularly come across people with these beliefs and they're utterly impossible to convince or instill even the slightest doubt in their believes.  They don't appear to be religiously motivated and seem to be basically normal other than this (as as "normal" as the average population is).  I've reached the point where I no longer even try and argue with them as it seems like wasted effort.  Some other types of denier are clearly driven by ideological or religious or racist ideas, but there doesn't seem to be anything like that in Flat-Earth people.

So I'm baffled and wonder if this has been studied at all.

There was some discussion about climate-change deniers in [this question](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/23973/does-denying-climate-change-work-similar-to-believing-the-earth-is-flat), but climate-change has many political, social and economic aspects, so I think it's different and more complex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [What makes people easily subscribe to pseudoscientific theories?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/1556/7001).